# i.onLCP is not a function

Tags: shopify-app

I am developing an embedded React App in shopify. When I open My app in the console than it shows a wierd type error that says

**Uncaught TypeError: web_vitals_1.onLCP is not a function**

Can anyone one help me in solving that error.

Comment: same problem here.